# how to publish vb.net project with MySQL database on another computer

Tags: mysql, vb.net, deployment, setup-deployment

I have an application using vb.net with MYSQL database in visual studio 2015 now i need to create a installation package to deploy the application to client computer.

I don't have any idea how to do this please anyone give tips how i can do this, im new with MYSQL.

Comment: Is the database going to have more than one user?

Comment: No, database only one user, "root"

Comment: I mean is there more than one user accessing the same  data? Not how many logins there are.

Comment: only one user ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, what technology are you using? If you are using entity framework you should have a .config file in your project, usually it's called app.Config, you can specify your `<connectionStrings>` there. Else if you use SqlConnection, you'll have to change that string.

Comment: <configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <connectionstring>
    <add name ="MySql_ConString" providername ="system.data.mysqlclient"
         connectionstring = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=Riyanali661;database=mydb">
    </add>
  </connectionstring>
    </configuration>
how i get connection string from app.config and open connection

Comment: yeah, if you have the database locally and you install your application on another machine you won't be able to find your database, so you'll need to change the parameters of the connectionstring and, depending on your needs, you'll have to setup the users permissions. Is it your issue related to that or you have trouble doing the package for the deployment?

Comment: yes im having trouble in deployment of application with mysql database on other machine ...

Comment: can you be more specific about your issue? do you get any type of error for example? If yes please post your error string

Comment: i need to install my vb.net application with mysql database on client/other computer, i need to know and understand ,  do i need to install mysql on client computer or is there any other way ? and what kind of connect i should have , connection in app.config or in module ?

Comment: well, if you want the database in local yes. But you'll need to specify the correct path in the connection string. The connection string you have works fine, you just will have to specify the correct path since you'll work on another machine, that's all

Comment: on my development computer every thing going fine , do i need to install mysql + database on client computer ?  and i have connection string in aap.config .........<connectionstring>
    <add name ="MySql_ConString" providername ="system.data.mysqlclient"
         connectionstring = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=Riyanali661;database=mydb">
    </add>
  </connectionstring> ...... how i can call and open  connection in module and form

Comment: yes, go for it and see what happens. If you get some sort of error post it here. You'll have to configure user and password though. It's root and Riyanali661 on your machine but the client computer won't have this information. Or else, if you configure a different user and password you'll have to specify it on the connection string.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have a distributed application.

Comment: yes its one pc and one user application now but after successfully deployment my next second step will be the client-server and then third step database on cloud forth step database and application both on cloud, that why i need to configure database and connections accordingly my further plan.. can i deployed my vb.net application on cloud ?

Comment: yes, in that case the connection string will be roughly the same for every installation. Just set up the users with the appropriate permissions to match your needs and you are good to go. The server address will be the same for everyone (it won't be localhost).